# select working initially in the blade but not the component

Tags: select, components, laravel-blade, dropdown, laravel-breeze

this is my initial code in laravel with breeze

```
<select id="building_status_id" class="w-full block mt-1 " name="building_status_id">
   @foreach ($building_statuses as $key)
   <option value="{{ $key->id }}"
    {{ (old('building_status_id') ?? $building->building_status_id) == $key->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
    {{ $key->building_status }}
   </option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

it is working perfectly

attempt to convert it into laravel component

```
    <select id="{{ $fieldName }}" name="{{ $fieldName }}" class="w-full block mt-1 " >
        @foreach ($options as $key)
            <option value="{{ $key->id }}"
                {{ (old('$fieldName') ?? $fieldTable-> $fieldName) == $key->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $key->$fieldColumn}} 
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

and use it from the blade with this line of code
`<x-edit-select fieldName="building_status_id"  fieldColumn="building_status" fieldTable="building" :options="$building_statuses" />`
i get this error `Attempt to read property "building_status_id" on string`